# Polymorphic Associations Pattern or AntiPattern or Both?

Tags: mysql

Multiple questions on this site and others relate to using a MySQL table definition where the name of the table is a column name.

For instance, for "notes" in a DB I am thinking of using the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Notes` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `table` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `row_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `note` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I keep reading all over the place that this is poor database design. I have figured out that this is called polymorphic association. [Polymorphic association is specifically listed as a SQL Anti-Pattern](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns). (or [in slides](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-object-oriented-models-in-sql#btnNext))

I have seen the drawbacks of the antipattern, but I have no requirement for doing any of those types of queries that I can think of.

For my app, I want to be able to write notes on just about every other row in the database. For potentially hundreds of other rows.

It is confusing that while this is listed as an AntiPattern, it seems to be a fundamental part of the [ruby ActiveRecord concept](http://maulanaruby.wordpress.com/2007/02/17/sti-vs-polymorphic-association/). Is the active record layer doing magic that makes this OK. (i.e. its polymorphic association at the record level, but not at the DB level)?

Specifically I would like to understand when/if using this SQL design is safe to use.

-FT

Comment: What does this mean: "For my app, I want to be able to write notes on just about every other row in the database."? Each row in a table would have some comments?

Comment: Well, as you no doubt know already, the problem with this anti-pattern is that one must create SQL dynamically via some higher level language in order to extract the final resultset.  Therefore one cannot obtain such results directly from within the database layer, which makes querying considerably more complex and more expensive.  Why not normalise your data, perhaps into the [Entity–attribute–value model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model)?

Comment: eggyal, that sounds like an answer to my question. If you would put that into an answer I would upvote you...